How to access each Web Server Instance in a Load Balancer Setup Hosted in Cloud like AWS or similar
I have a Web Application developed in .Net Core 6.0 meant to serving APIs to various clients.
It is hosted in AWS. Since the hits started to increase, A LB environment was created and 2 more server instances were added. So when ever network traffic increases, new instances of servers come live and go down when not needed.
So far this works fine.
There are some internal variables and settings in the application which are altered by an external application by calling a specific Controller/Action (for example Search/Resetcache). This reloads and resets some internal classes and variables at runtime.
This was OK when there was only a single server, but now, the external call invokes only a single server (to which the LB directs). I want all the servers to respond, but there is only one domain URL and it would direct to a single active server.
I thought of accessing with the IP, but NW team says that the IPs would change dynamically when server instances come live and down based on the NW traffic.
Can anyone help here .....
